# How to hide mouse pointer when moved inside gvim in windows

Tags: vim

I have been trying to find a way to hide mouse pointer altogether ( just to force myself to use the keyboard instead of mouse) I am using windows 7. How do I proceed with this

Comment: I think vim has no control over your mouse pointer. It can access the cursor alone.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use gvim on linux, and in my vimrc file I've defined this

```
set mouse-=a
set mousehide
```

It hides and disables the mouse. I do not know if it works in Windows.

Comment: In windows it seems to disable the right click and mouse click as selection but the pointer is visible